# How to test particular conditions in controller layer?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, testing, mocking

So... I have a simple method "addUser" in my controller. I want to test the first if-statement when user with given email already exists in database. In setUp method I create a sample user with fields like firstname, lastname, email etc. When I put the exacttly same email as a *param* in mockMvc I expected it to return the *"register/new-register"* but instead it returns *"register/register-success"*. Im newbie as it comes to testing, couldn't find an answer for this problem. Here's my code. Please tell me how to test this part or at least if im even doing it right

```
 @PostMapping("/register")
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute @Valid User user,
                          BindingResult bindResult) {
        if(userService.isAlreadyRegistered(user.getEmail())){
            bindResult.rejectValue("email", "email.exists", "Email already in database");
            return "register/new-register";
        }
        else if(bindResult.hasErrors())
            return "register/new-register";
        else {
            userService.addWithDefaultRole(user);
            return "register/register-success";
        }
    }
```

```
@Test
    @WithMockUser
    public void addUserExists() throws Exception{

        mockMvc.perform(post("/user/register")
                .param("firstName", "test")
                .param("lastName", "test")
                .param("email", "test@test.com")
                .param("password", "test"))
                .andExpect(view().name("register/new-register"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

Comment: Stack overflow does not allow people with new accounts to upload images to keep people from pasting their code as an image. You should post your code as text form in to the question! This is really important since there may be licensing issues with code that is hosted on third party sites! Please include your code as text form in this question!

Comment: Done as you said :) Will remember that, thanks!